# Find if two nodes are connected in a directed graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

Given a directed graph implemented using `HashMap<String, String>`, find if two nodes are connected.

For example:

`"b"--->"a"<---"c"`

```
Map<String, String> graph = new HashMap<>();
map.put("b", "a");
map.put("c", "a");
```

`"b"` and `"c"` are connected.

I found a [post](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-if-there-is-a-path-between-two-vertices-in-a-given-graph/) in which the graph is a directed graph but the solution is to find if there is a path between two nodes. My question is different because `"b"` and `"c"` in above example are considered connected even though there is no path between `"b"` and `"c"`.

Comment: In the second example, `b` and `c` are not connected. There is one edge from `a` to `c`. You changed the mapping for `a` with the second `put` call.

Comment: @NeilLocketz Oops, sorry, I deleted that example.

Comment: The "solution" to which you linked determines whether there is a *path* from one node to another in the (directed) graph.  That is not the same as the problem you have presented: in your example, there is no path from "b" to "c", yet you still consider them connected.  **Any** solution to your actual problem is a better solution than a non-solution such as the one you linked.

Comment: You can always convert it to bidirectional graph and be able to start from `b` or `c`.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question.  In my example, `"b"` and `"c"` are considered connected.

Comment: With all the edits you no longer have a question, at least not an on-topic one.  The implied "how can I implement this" is too broad.  I will nevertheless observe that one of the common tools for graph theory problems related to connectedness is the [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).  Such a data structure could be applied to your problem to yield a very efficient solution that does not require you to modify the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real difference between your representation and the one used in the link you provided. They used an array of `LinkedList<Integer>` which maps to each node all adjacent nodes.
You also have this information, every key of your map is linked to all adjacent nodes.

But first note that your representation is very restricted. You restrict a node to have only one neighboor. You can change this by changing the type of the `value` class to `Set<String>` instead of `String` for example.

Simply reimplement the BFS or DFS with your structure or transform your version to theirs and use their code directly. However the first solution will be faster but requires you to understand how those searches work.
But do not be afraid, they are easy and there are good articles online, for example at Wikipedia:

- [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)
- [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Comment: In the linked example it says that: "As another example, there is no path from 3 to 0." But according to OP, it needs to have path from 3 to 0.

Comment: I see. That means OP wants to interpret the graph `undirected` instead of `directed`? Then he needs to add pseudo-edges for the other direction for each edge. As otherwise a node can not know his neighboors from the other direction.

Comment: Yes, @Zabuza, apparently the OP wants to evaluate connectedness in the graph that would be obtained by converting his directed graph to an undirected one.  There may be more alternatives than "add[ing] pseudo-edges", depending on what exactly you mean by that.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question. In my example, `"b"` and `"c"` are considered connected.

Comment: Yes, that means you are interpreting a directed graph as undirected graph (you do not care for the direction the edges are pointing). In general this would not be the case and thus the search will not work without modifications because how should `a` know that `c` points to it? Only `c` knows it in your structure. A very easy fix would be to create copies of all edges that point in the other direction, so `if b ---> a` then also add `a ---> b`. However there may be better solutions, search for `reachability undirected graph`. But I think they will all require you to change your model.